# Why is my volume sometimes not working when I start the computer?

Tags: 11.10, sound, volume-control

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Basically the volume only starts at certain times.  I can reboot my machine and sometimes the volume will work, sometimes it won't.

If I run:

```
alsamixer
```

It shows the volume, I can adjust it.   I have no idea why this randomly works, it seems to fall more on the side of not working and is starting to get quite annoying as anytime I try and watching a video on the net it crashes chrome because audio is not working.

I'm starting to really miss the days when Ubuntu was less flashy but just worked.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your hardware setup? I'm not very knowledgeable on this topic, but to me it sounds like it could be a driver issue.

Comment: Running 64-bit version.  Would you like dmesg output?  It could very well be a driver vs. kernel mismatch.  I've had that in the past, what is strange it is works about half the time, I can reboot and the other half it doesn't work.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has since been resolved with updates. It was probably an issue with the kernel as it has since been updated and haven't had the problem in sometime.